# how to write __asm__ goto inline assembly

Tags: gcc, inline-assembly

I m using a GCC compiler. I want to insert some inline instructions into C. Non-branching instructions are inserted successfully using **__asm__** directive, as follows:

```
  __asm__ volatile (
            "add %[my_out], %[my_op1], %[my_op2]\n"
            : [my_out] "=&r" (array[3])
            : [my_op1] "r" (array[0]),[my_op2] "r" (array[1])
    );
```

But i cant inset a branch/jump instruction. Compilation gives the following error:

```
../test.c:5: error: expected '(' before 'goto'
../test.c:5: error: expected identifier or '*' before 'volatile'
```

I tried the following code:

```
unsigned int array[10] = { 0x22, 0x12,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
int main() {


  __asm__ goto volatile (
                "jp %l[label]\n"
                : /*no output*/
                : [my_op1] "r" (array[0]),[my_op2] "r" (array[1])
                : /*no cobblers*/
                : label
        );


  return 0;

label:

  __asm__ volatile (
                "add %[my_out], %[my_op1], %[my_op2]\n"
                : [my_out] "=&r" (array[3])
                : [my_op1] "r" (array[0]),[my_op2] "r" (array[1])
        );


  return 0;

}
```

can you please help in correcting this code?
Regards

Comment: place `volatile` keyword **before** `goto` rather than after.In your case you can remove the `volatile` in your first statement given that you have no output (or input/output) constraints. When you have none of those `asm` is has an implicit volatile. Your second `asm` would still have to be marked volatile

Comment: To add to what Michael said, since asm goto *cannot* have outputs, and since asm statements without outputs are implicitly volatile, all asm goto statements are implicitly volatile.  You might also want to check out the [docs](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html) which would have shown you the order for the qualifiers.

Comment: Thanks. I tried both by inserting volatile before goto and also without volatile. It gives the same error.

Comment: That should have worked.  What's your target hw/os?  And what version of gcc are you using?

Comment: What version of GCC are you using? You can use `gcc -v` to find out. When you made the fix suggested did the error change?

Comment: I m using ASIPmeister tool, that is used to customize a basis processor and generate VHDL files and also an extended GCC compiler to support newly added custom instructions. ASIPmeister uses gcc-4.2.2 as a basis for extending.

Comment: Then I use this extended GCC to compile my C code.

Comment: `asm goto` wasn't available until GCC 4.5

Comment: @MichaelPetch Thanks, is there any solution now? gcc-4.2.2 is provided by the ASIPmeister team, and I doubt I can not upgrade it.

Comment: I can't think of one that doesn't get into undefined behavior. You could write the function in assembly. Would be curious what problem is being solved by doing this? Efficiency? Missed compiler optimizations?

Comment: Some part of C code is to be replace by a custom instruction for example. That is why we want to use it inside the C code. Non-branch instructions can be inserted properly but I have problem with branch. For, example if we have to define an instruction Branch Greater than or Equal (bge rs1, rs2, label.)

Comment: have you tried using a jmp to a label?

use .Lfoo%=: to get a uniquified label in an inline-asm block.